# How to combine two class in css

Tags: html, css

here my two class classA  and classB  i want classB inherit style of classA
and use only classB

```css
.classA{ width:100px;}
.classB{ height:100px;}

<div class="classB"></div>
```

Comment: It's quite unclear, please add some details what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe you're confused by the fact that they're called classes – plain CSS does not have a concept of inheritance (like OO classes) that lets you say "`classB` sets all properties of `classA`, and then some", though CSS pre-processors like SASS and LessCSS do (by duplicating the properties at compile time)

Answer (score 3):

```
.classA{ width:100px;}
.classB{ height:100px;}

<div class="classA classB"></div>
```

Comment: no you uses two class name in div i want inherit classA style in classB and use classB

Answer (score 0):

maybe this type helps :

```
.classA,.classB
{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
}

<div class="classB"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want combine these class and use only classB

It seems that you want only classB?

```css
div {
    background-color: #ff0000; /* For Visibility */
}
.classB {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="classB"></div>
```